# Load MP3 files without using the Content Pipeline

Tags: c#, audio, xna, mp3, content-pipeline

I'm writing a game in XNA 4.0 that needs to be able to load MP3 sounds from files on disk. I can't use the content pipeline as that would prevent users from loading their own music. I've looked around a bit, and found a good question that featured a C# Ogg library, but I'd rather stick with MP3 for simplicity.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `Song.FromUri()`?

Comment: Yes - it chokes on paths with spaces, and I can't get it to play by reflecting an internal constructor, either. I don't think it's the right option for me.

Comment: Well, have you tried to load a file with a path with no spaces?

Comment: I cannot guarantee that all audio files will have no spaces in their paths.